# Lemmas to characterize Eistenstein primes

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here are lemmas to characterize Gaussian primes

> **Lemma1** Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Then, the Legendre symbol $(-1/p)=1$
>
> **Lemma2** Let $p$ be an odd prime such that $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Then, there are integers $a,b$ such that $p=a^2+b^2$.

Lemma1 implies that $p$ is not a prime in the Gaussian integers and hence $p$ can be written as a product of two primes $\pi,\pi'$. Then, this implies that the norm of $\pi$ is $p$, hence proving the Lemma 2. Then, Lemma2 characterized Gaussian primes easily.

Just like these lemmas for characterizing Gaussian primes, I want to know lemmas for characterizing Eisenstein primes before I prove it by myself. (I don't want to waste my time too much)

So, what are meaningful lemmas to prove the below statement?

> Let $\pi$ be an Eisenstein prime such that $|\pi|^2$ is not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\pi$ associates to a prime $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\equiv 2 \pmod 3$. Also the converse holds.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding precisely, but the corresponding lemmas are that (-3/p) = 1 if and only if p \cong 1 mod 3 and that for such primes they can be written as x^2+xy+y^2, x,y\in \Z. (Also that the Eisenstein integers are a PID => UFD.)

Comment: @JohnBrevik That seems exactly the one I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnBrevik: It should be $x^2-xy+y^2$, right ?

Comment: It's generally written with a +, but either way generates the same set of primes (just substitute y with -y.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the book of Ireland and Rosen the primes in the ring of Eisenstein integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ are classified as follows:

*Proposition*: Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are primes in $\mathbb{Z}$. If $q\equiv 2(3)$, then $q$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. If $p\equiv 1(3)$, then $p=N(\pi)$, where $\pi$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. (Finally, $3=-\omega^2(1-\omega)^2$, and $1-\omega$ is prime.)

The proof uses quadratic reciprocity for $p\equiv 1(3)$ (to show that $(-3/p)=1$ for such primes), and uses the norm in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (i.e., $p=x^2-xy+y^2=N(\pi)$, $\pi=x+y\omega$).

Comment: Thank you for stating the proposition :) I had no chance to read that book.

Comment: You are welcome!